# Webgrid Format of datetime and setting style

Tags: razor, webgrid

I'm struggline with syntax gremlins with the WebGrid. In my normal razor markup i format a date inside my foreach like so

```
<td>
        @String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss}", item.complianceedatetime)
    </td>
```

and I set my column width like so

```
<th width="150px">
        Download Date/Time
    </th>
```

How would I do this with the Grid.Column syntax

```
grid.Column("complianceedatetime", "Download Date/Time", ?, ?)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
@grid.GetHtml(
    column: grid.Columns(
              grid.Column("Complianceedatetime", "Download Date / Time", 
format: @<text>@item.complianceedatetime.ToString("MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss")</text>)
            )
)
```

I know this works because I have this exact code in my project:

```
grid.Column(
            "PublishDate",
            canSort: true,
            format: @<text>@item.PublishDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")</text>
        ),
```

Comment: Changing `@item.complianceedatetime` to `@item.Complianceedatetime` would make the top snippet work properly. Otherwise, the second code snippet works.

Answer (score 4):

If `DateTime` Property is defined as (can contain `null`):

```
public DateTime? WorkedDate { get; set; }
```

Use this format:

```
grid.Column("WorkedDate", "Last Worked On",
   format: (item) => item.WorkedDate != null 
   ? item.WorkedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yy") : "", canSort: true)
```

Otherwise if it is defined as below (can't be `null`), it will have either actual date or `.MinDate` as the default.

```
public DateTime WorkedDate { get; set; }
```

Use format:

```
grid.Column("WorkedDate", "Last Worked On",
   format: (item) => item.WorkedDate != DateTime.MinValue ? 
   item.WorkedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yy") : "", canSort: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
@grid.GetHtml(
    column: grid.Columns(
              grid.Column("Complianceedatetime", "Download Date / Time", format: (item) => string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss}", item.complianceedatetime)
            )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this option for better globalization

```
    @grid.GetHtml(
        column: grid.Columns(
                  grid.Column("Complianceedatetime", "Download Date / Time", 
                  format: @@String.Format("{0:g}",complianceedatetime))
                )
    )
```

Comment: This doesn't work either. People, check your code please. It takes a minute to run it. It would really help for those of us trying to understand and learn the syntax if you would make sure you are posting correct code.